# How to get a hash in a Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, web

I have a Rails model with 2 fields: 'name' and 'bucket'. Name is a string and bucket is a hash of the form: bucket: {red: 1, green: 2, ...}.

I created a rails form to populate these fields but while name works properly, the rest don't even appear as values.

This is the point that it doesn't work, when I am trying to bind a color to a value provided by the user, with default value 0.

```
<% @board.fetch_all_colors.each do |color|  %>
    <%= form.label color.to_sym, "#{color}:" %>
    <div class="input">
      <%= form.text_field :bucket, value: 0.0 %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The thing is that when I debug and print params, I only find an empty bucket hash. One problem seems to be that because of the each loop, I only get the last input text.

**Edit**: I found a workaround that takes me half there. Instead of a text_field, I am using the following:

```
text_field_tag "bucket[]"
```

The above uses my input normally and puts it in an array. The problem with that is that since the input is dynamic (and could have labels come and go, I can't guarantee for the position of the array (e.g. that 3rd position is always 'red'). Can I use something like the above but with a hash?

Answer (score 0):

While JSON-like objects are supported by rails DB drivers, the rest of the rails stack doesn't have seamless API's for specifying multi-value column attributes.

You'll need to dynamically build your hash in the controller from custom-defined attributes which don't have a 1:1 mapping to your model.

Alternatively in a more Rails-like fashion, you could use a `has_many` relation, storing your `buckets` as a separate model in the database which is joined to your `Board` model. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` would help you do this.